# observable event filters and timeout

Tags: filter, timeout, rxjs, observable

I am very new Rxjs observable and need help with two questions.
I have this piece of code:

```
const resultPromise = this.service.data
            .filter(response => data.Id === 'dataResponse')
            .filter((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Values.Success) 
            .take(1)
            .timeout(timeoutInSeconds)
            .map((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Values.Token)
            .toPromise();
```

I have following basic questions:

1- How can I change .timeout(timeoutInSeconds) to add a message so that I can debug/log later which response it fails? I looked at .timeout syntax in rxjs and didn't see an option to include any message or something.

2-I know .filter((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Values.Success) will filter to responses with response.Values.Success but is there a syntax where I can do like this for an observable:

```
const resultPromise = this.service.data
                    .filter(response => data.Id === 'dataResponse')
                    .magicSyntax((response: dataResponseMessage) => {
                        if (response.Values.Success) {
                            // do something
                        } else {
                            // do something else
                        }
                    });
```

Thank you so much in advance and sorry if these are basic/dumb questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using at least Rxjs version 5.5 which introduced [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). From the docs - these can "...be accessed in *rxjs/operators* (notice the pluralized "operators"). These are meant to be a better approach for pulling in just the operators you need than the "patch" operators found in rxjs/add/operator/*."

If you aren't using pipeable operators, instead of passing the operators to `pipe()` like I did below, you can chain them using the dot notation you use in your example.

I suggest referring to [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) for some additional info about the operators in RxJS, paired with examples.

The RxJS team has also created a [BETA documentation](https://beta-rxjsdocs.firebaseapp.com/) reference.

### **Explanation**

I assumed the first `filter` is receiving the **response** and filtering by **response.Id instead of data.Id**. If that wasn't a typo, you can keep the filter the same.

I added an extra line between the operators for presentation only.

[mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) is an operator that takes a function that returns an Observable, which it will automatically subscribe to. I'm returning [of()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html) here, which creates an Observable that just emits the value provided to it.

catch was renamed to [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) in RxJS [5.5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), and pipeable operators were also added, which add support for the `.pipe()` operator.

If you don't want to do anything besides logging the error, you can return [empty()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/empty.html), which will immediately call `complete()` on the source Observable without emitting anything. [EMPTY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-9) is preferred if you are using version 6.

**Optional:** Instead of using `filter()` and then `take(1)`, you could use the [first()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) operator, which returns a boolean, just like `filter()`, and unsubscribes from the source Observable after it returns `true` once.

```
import {EMPTY, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, filter, take, mergeMap, timeout} from 'rxjs/operators';

const resultPromise = service.data.pipe(

    // I assumed you meant response.Id, instead of data.Id
    filter((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Id === 'dataResponse'),

    take(1),

    // mergeMap accepts a value emitted from the source Observable, and expects an Observable to be returned, which it subscribes to
    mergeMap((response: dataResponseMessage) => {
        if (response.Values.Success) {
            return of('Success!!');
        }
        return of('Not Success');
    }),

    timeout(timeoutInMilliseconds),

    // catch was renamed to catchError in version 5.5.0
    catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return EMPTY;  // The 'complete' handler will be called. This is a static property on Observable
        // return empty(); might be what you need, depending on version.
    })
).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 1):

First question
If you reach timeout the operator will return you an error which can be caught with `.catch` operator

```js
const resultPromise = this.service.data
            .filter(response => data.Id === 'dataResponse')
            .filter((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Values.Success) 
            .take(1)
            .timeout(timeoutInSeconds)
            .catch(e=>{
              //do your timeout operation here ... 
              return Observable.Of(e)
            })
            .map((response: dataResponseMessage) => response.Values.Token)
            .toPromise();
```

Second question simply replace magicSyntax with map or mergemap depends what you want to return from this operation. it is perfectly fine to do `if` in side the block.

Comment: .catch not working, saying there is no catch on type of observable<dataResponseMessage>

Comment: which version rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

1- you can use .do() to console.log your response.

```
.filter(..).do(response => console.log(response))
```

2- you can use .mergeMap()